# How to turn a point layer into classified proportional circles in QGIS 2.12?

Tags: qgis, style, circle

I'm trying to style a point layer representing cities around the Mediterranean following these two rules :

- The points should be represented as proportional circles, following a classification in 5 classes ;
- The circles should be coloured according to the five classes, on a graduated scale from yellow to red.

I tried different things, including mixing classification and data defined styling, but didn't succeed yet.

Answer (score 2):

As @Papierwolf mentioned, there are a number of ways. One of which is to directly style your point layer using the **Graduated style**. I made an example where I:

1. Selected an `id` column (which for me contained ascending values, 5 to 10)
2. Set the *Color ramp* to `YlOrRd`
3. Classified 5 classes then right-clicked each class and selected the **Change size** option.

[image: Graduated style]

4. From the pop-up menu, selected the **Size Assistant** option

[image: Size options]

5. Then played around with setting the various sizes and values for my `id` column.

[image: Size Assistant options]

Answer (score 1):

Size by kategory:

- Use the *buffer* tool from Vektor menü to create a Polygon-Layer representing your cities
- The source layer is your pointlayer
- The buffer distance is given by your classification field or a field you calculate based off your classification....
- The new Polygon-Layer will inherrit all the attributes from your pointlayer  for the next step

Coloring in the style tab:

- Chose kategorize from the drop down menü at the top
- Chose row: "category" (that should be the row you specified the categories by size in)
- push the classify button to find every unique "category" and chose the colours you prefer

Hint: There is more than just one way to reach your goal, this is the easiest I know. It may not be the best or smartest solution but it works.